# How to create a URL in Java?

Tags: java, android, url

I want to make an app that shows a list of books that relate to a given keyword. I made the ListView, EditText view and a search button. The layout is given below:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_query_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="@string/hint" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_button1"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Results" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The XML for a single item in the list is given below.

list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail_imageview"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/kite_runner" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/title_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="The Kite Runner"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/author_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_textview"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Khaled Hosseini"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/publisher_texview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/author_textview"
                android:text="Penguin Books"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using the Google Books API query to access the book list.

I have the base URL and I now need to add the value in the EditText view to this URL.

The custom adapter for the list view is given below.

```
package com.example.shara.booklistapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by shara on 12/17/2017.
 */

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Blist> {
    public ListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Blist> blists) {
        super(context, 0, blists);
    }

    public String rslt;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listitemview = convertView;
        if (listitemview == null) {
            listitemview = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        }
        Blist blist = getItem(position);

         EditText search_query = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.search_query_text_view);

        Button search_button = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.search_button1);

        search_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String searchquery = search_query.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        ImageView bookthumbnail = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_imageview);

        TextView title = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);

        TextView author = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.author_textview);

        TextView publisher = listitemview.findViewById(R.id.publisher_texview);


        return listitemview;
    }
}
```

I am using another class named BookQueryUtils to create the URL and to do the HTTP request and JSON parsing.

I want to access the value of EditText view from BookQueryUtils class and then append it to the base URL.

Also how can I call the AsyncTaskLoader inside the BookQueryUtils class when the button is pressed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley, example:

```
String url = "https://example.com";

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e("RESPONSE", response);


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

                stringRequest.setTag("LOL");
                queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks ffor your reply but as this is a part of an ongoing course, i cannot use external libraries to do this. I think i have found a way to do it.

Comment: I need the list view to fetch the data and display it when the search button is pressed. How can i successfully bind the button press to the HTTP request.